# How to include values from files into your code

Tags: c, while-loop, fopen

I have this structure Student Record that I'd like to fill with values from two files NamesIDsDataFile and MarksDataFile temporarily but when I run the loop only values from NamesIDsDataFile go into the structure. I've put the print statement inside the while loop to see what the issue was and when I run the code nothing prints out. Could someone please explain how to print the values from MarksDataFile.

```
struct StudentRecord {

char FirstNames[MAXLENGTH];
char LastNames[MAXLENGTH];
int IDNums;
int Marks;

};

    FILE * NamesIDsDataFile;
    FILE * MarksDataFile;

    while (fscanf(NamesIDsDataFile,"%s%s%d",&(SRecords.FirstNames[0]), 
    &(SRecords.LastNames[0]), &(SRecords.IDNums)) != EOF) {

        fscanf(MarksDataFile,"%d",&(SRecords.Marks));

        printf("%d", SRecords.Marks);

    }

    fclose(NamesIDsDataFile);
    fclose(MarksDataFile);
```

Comment: Step 1: `fscanf(...) != EOF` --> `fscanf(...) == 3`.  2: Post sample input, output and expected output.

Comment: I assume you're opening these files somewhere?

Comment: Can you show the few example data of the both file please.?

Comment: Did my answer help you to solve.? :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to to so by little change in your code is :

```
while (fscanf(NamesIDsDataFile," %s %s %d ",&(SRecords.FirstNames[0]), 
    &(SRecords.LastNames[0]), &(SRecords.IDNums)) != EOF) 
{
      fscanf(MarksDataFile," %d ",&(SRecords.Marks));

      printf("%d", SRecords.Marks);
}
```

but, if the if the text file is not always same and not structured very well, you should not go with above code, instead use following code.

here is the best way to do it:

```
int ret1,ret2;
while (ret =fscanf(NamesIDsDataFile," %s %s %d ",&(SRecords.FirstNames[0]), 
&(SRecords.LastNames[0]), &(SRecords.IDNums))) {

    if(ret == EOF)
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        ret2 = fscanf(MarksDataFile," %d ",&(SRecords.Marks));
        if(ret2 == EOF || ret2 == 0)
        {
            break;
        }else
        {
            printf("%d", SRecords.Marks);

        }
    }
}

fclose(NamesIDsDataFile);
fclose(MarksDataFile);
```

ret is an int variable whose value will be :

- EOF, if the pointer is reached end of file.
- 0, if no input matched with the variable
- >0, number of matched variables with the file input

Comment: I have updated the answer as there was a mistake in code. now it should work.! please check out and select as answer if it works :)